# AWS Amplify build error: "Basic Auth is not supported for SSR apps."

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I've created a very basic NextJS application to get familiar with the CI/CD pipeline AWS's Amplify service provides and I've run across an error that I'm not able to find any resources on.

`Error: Build failed: Basic Auth is not supported for SSR apps. Please disable Basic Auth before deploying your SSR app.`

I have two branches that I am pushing up to Amplify, `main` and `develop`. When I push to `develop` on Github and my pipeline triggers on Amplify I get the build error pictured below. What's strange is, when I merged `develop` into `master` locally and then pushed up the changes to my repo, the build on my Amplify `main` pipeline completed without issue despite it being the exact same code.

I'm curious why that is, I've tried the reconnecting the webhook suggestion it provides (both before and after doing the develop -> main merge experiment) yet that doesn't seem to resolve anything.

Again, my App is a vanilla NextJS application with some eslint/husky configurations. There's really nothing there and when I first created the develop branch and hooked it up to Amplify it was building just fine. I'd appreciate some help here since the error message doesn't result in anything when I google it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Access control must be disabled when using the SSR app.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-control.html

Click the app from the AWS Amplify console.
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba0gd.jpg)